# HashSet doesn't remove dupes with overridden equality

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `Pair`, which needs to have an overridden equality operator due to the two values it stores being interchangeable, the code is this

**Pair.cs**

```
public class Pair
    {
        protected bool Equals(Pair other)
        {
            return (Equals(A, other.A) && Equals(B, other.B)) || (Equals(A, other.B) && Equals(B, other.A));
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            return obj.GetType() == this.GetType() && Equals((Pair) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return ((A != null ? A.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ (B != null ? B.GetHashCode() : 0);
            }
        }

        public readonly Collision A, B;

        public Pair(Collision a, Collision b)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Pair a, Pair b)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(a, b))
                return true;

            if ((object)a == null || (object)b == null)
                return false;

            return (a.A == b.A && a.B == b.B) || (a.A == b.B && a.B == b.A);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Pair a, Pair b)
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }
    }
```

I had ReSharper add the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, I know `Equals` is ok, but is `GetHashCode` outputting the correct value?

I have a `HashSet<Pair>` that I use to store the pairs, and I need to ensure there are no duplications in this list, however when I add the pairs to a `HashSet` it doesn't remove the duplicates.

Just for clarification, this would be a duplicate:

```
Pair a = new Pair(objecta, objectb);
Pair b = new Pair(objectb, objecta);
HashSet<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<Pair>();
pairs.Add(a);
pairs.Add(b);
return pairs.Count(); //Count() returns 2 when it should be 1!
```

Comment: Generally, when mathematicians say "pair" they mean an *ordered* pair. You are defying the norm and should consider renaming to `UnorderedPair`.

Comment: You should read this before you attempt to write another Equals / GetHashCode pair: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @Jason Pair is just a placeholder name, I was just testing my underlying system, I'm going to rename it Manifold as it will contain objects used for collision detection and response.

Comment: Then call it `Manifold` from the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GetHashCode` implementation does not return the same value for (A, B) and (B, A). The `HashSet` checks if it already contains a given hash at the moment of insertion. If it doesn't, then the object will be considered new.

If you correct your `GetHashCode`, then at the moment of inserting the second `Pair` the `HashSet` will see that the hash code already exists and verify equality with the other objects sharing the same hash code.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove this: *397

If they are considered duplicates, they must **return the same int from GetHashCode()**. (However, if they are not considered duplicates they are still allowed to return the same int, that will only affect performance).

Comment: Nevermind, I was debugging it wrong, it still isnt deleting the dupes. :(

Comment: @redcodefinal Resharper threw in the * 397 exactly to make sure that (A, B) and (B, A) have diffrent hash codes! It's something you usually want, unless you are making a `Pair` object. ;) EDIT: Well you removed your comment but I'll leave this here anyway

Comment: @Vache Sorry, I set a break point at the wrong brace and thought it had already done everything. Turns out it still isnt filtering dupes. :( I editted the code above the reflect the changes I made.

Comment: @Vache, Apperently I was wrong again.. The GetHashCode fix above works fine. Thanks for the help.